# How to convert str to a float?

Tags: python, list

I imported a list full of floats as strings, and i tried to convert them to floats, but this error kept popping up

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\peter\Documents\coding\projects\LineFitting.py", line 12, in <module>
    StockPriceFile = float(value.strip(''))
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

this is what i did to try and convert the list:

```
#1
for value in range(0, len(StockPriceFile)):
    StockPriceFile[value] = float(StockPriceFile[value])
#2
for value in StockPriceFile:
    value = float(value)
#3
StockPriceFile[0] = StockPriceFile[0].strip('[]')
for value in StockPriceFile:
    StockPriceFile = float(value.strip(''))
```

(Sample Of Data)

```
['[36800.]', '36816.666666666664', '36816.666666666664', '36833.333333333336', '36866.666666666664']
```

where its being written:

```
Data_AvgFile.write(str(Average) + ',')
```

What does this mean? and how can i fix it? it works fine when i do it one by one.

(also tell me if you need more data, i dont know if this is sufficient)

Comment: The string has `[]` around it, so it can't be parsed as a float. You need to remove those first.

Comment: still gives me the same error sadly

Comment: *"I imported a list full of floats as strings"* - well there's your problem.  You should, if at all possible, keep things as their proper types, and only convert when necessary.  If you need a list of floats, don't convert to `str`.  (Assuming you have control over the code that is doing that step.)

Comment: I was not able to control this as the data all came from a .write() and i had to convert to strings

Comment: I’m not seeing any example data? What does the data look like? Are there any strings that cannot be converted to `float` you could print the value before conversion to check and that would also let you know which value is failing.

Comment: Please provide a sample of the data you are trying to process. It's hard to know the problem without that. In other words, please show a [mcve]

Comment: Is the sample data a string containing those characters? A list of strings? The dump of a text file? Again. Need a [mcve]

Comment: That can't be the data. The error message says it looks like `[36800.]`.

Comment: Added! thank you for telling me, anyways its just a list full of strings with float values

Comment: Ill add a bigger sample size @Barmar

Comment: Are you reading a file? Is `StockPriceFile` the list you show, or a file containing lists on each line?

Comment: StockPriceFile is the shown list, yes

Comment: That looks more like a string that could be made into a list… the error does seem to indicate it’s trying to convert a value that includes non-numeric characters. Can you show where you’re reading/writing the values from/to the file? For example if the file looks like `’[3578.134, 3578., 8737.123]’` I would venture to say it is a JSON string that should be evaluated first…

Comment: @Barmar seems to have the answer with your sample data… he proved it works with a link.

Comment: It would seem your problem is in writing the data to file. There are inconsistencies that are showing up when trying to read the file back.

Comment: It seems like it, ill review the file and get back to this, sorry about this.

Comment: No worries, based on your `write` line you’re making something of a CSV file, but not utilizing the library. We may be able to help you write the file better if we could see how, what you’re doing. I understand it may not be a CSV solvable item, but thought I would throw it out as it may help you as well.

Comment: Ok, i fixed the data, and it now looks like ^, however this time i get a error of ^ what does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

```
for value in StockPriceFile:
    stock_price = float(value.strip('[]'))
    print(stock_price)
```

`strip()` will remove the `[]` characters around the value.

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/BB7eAs)

Comment: Thank you for the Answer, however this resulted in the same error yet again, the data looks sort of like ['1','2','3']

Comment: I've added a demo link showing that it works with the data you gave.

Comment: I have tried it again, and the error is again:```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\peter\Documents\coding\projects\dad thing\Stock stuff\Stock-LineFitting.py", line 11, in <module>
    stock_price = float(value.strip('[]'))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '21800.021800.0'``` EDIT: just saw this i am not sure why there are two decimal places on some

Comment: `21800.021800.0` isn't a valid number, it has too many decimal points. For some reason you have two numbers combined, when they should be in separate elements of the list.

Comment: There's nothing like that in your sample data. `strip()` isn't doing that, it's a problem with the data.

Answer (score 0):

As long you have the brackets "[ ]" in you'r string you cant convert it to a a number as that would make it invalid so do letters and most symbols the dot (.) is an exception for float.

```
>>> print(float('[36800.]'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[36800.]'
>>> print(float('36800.'))
36800.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = ['[36800.]', '36816.666666666664', '36816.666666666664', '36833.333333333336', '36866.666666666664']
[float(f.strip('[]')) for f in l]
```

Output:

```
[36800.0,
 36816.666666666664,
 36816.666666666664,
 36833.333333333336,
 36866.666666666664]
```